# Deploying Office Add-In (React) on Azure Web Apps running a Windows Server

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service, office-addins

I created an Office Add-In using React. I ran it locally and deployed it successfully on DigitalOcean, however, when deploying on Azure Web App Service (as requested by my client), I keep running into problems.

As I found out, Linux is not supported to run Office Add-Ins. I am running a Windows Server and whenever I deploy the App, I get the following error:

[image]

This is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I do not have an `index.html` file, since Office Add-ins require the entrypoint of the app to be `taskpane.html`. However, I set `taskpane.html` as the default document in the Web App settings.

I would appreciate the help.

Thanks.